# Jenkins pipeline inside docker using latest upstream image

Tags: docker, jenkins

We have a Jenkinsfile with a declarative pipeline using a Docker container to run on the build node.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            registryCredentialsId   'foobar-registry'
            registryUrl             'https://foobar.com/'
            image                   'bar:latest'
            label                   'foobar && docker'
            reuseNode               false
            args                    ''
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Steps run inside docker here ...') {
            steps {
                sh "python3 -m pycodestyle ."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works except for the fact that the build node docker instance is caching the `bar:latest` image and not pulling the latest from the upstream registry when an update exists. If we update the Docker image in the repository we have to manually clobber the build node docker cache, which is a pain.

We can manually add versions to the image builds referenced in the Jenkinsfile, and update the version every time we modify the Docker image, but for our develop branch we would quite like this pipeline to just pull the latest image on the repository (ideally with caching if no changes are detected).

This can't be an uncommon needed, but struggling to find documentation for the docker plugin (in particular for declarative jobs), so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After rummaging in the source code, the fix is:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            ...
            alwaysPull   true
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This will use the local docker cache, and only pull new images when things are changed.